# What data structure would you use to model a Blockchain?

Tags: scala, data-structures, blockchain

I'm working on a functional mini-Blockchain implementation in Scala. I've given this a lot of thought but still can't comprehend the most suitable data structure to model a Blockchain. Specifically :-

1.) It can't be a simple Linked list/Stack, because there are forks , which means that two different blocks can refer to the same Block.Should it be a List of top blocks , i.e. a list of topmost(heightwise) blocks ? I can then traverse the blockchain by starting my traversal from either of the topmost blocks.
2.) How do I make a block point to the previous block ? I know that every block has the hash of the previous block. But how is that enough for me to go from a block to the block it refers to in my blockchain data structure ?

Would really appreciate any help I can get. 
,

Comment: your question is too broad to have a good answer in SO. but try to google some java/scala implementations and you could have a good start. For instance: https://medium.com/programmers-blockchain/create-simple-blockchain-java-tutorial-from-scratch-6eeed3cb03fa

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to make a functional toy blockchain, a linked list would be suitable (a non-toy implementation my want to look at persistence options outside of memory).

To address your first question, when the chain forks, you now have two different chains, just with the same first few blocks. You can in fact have two nodes in a (immutable) linked list [point to the same node](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/W4ARW4j/1) without concern.

To the second, define your block's hash as a function of the last block's hash. Assuming you call the rest of the blocks in the chain `tail` you could say a block's hash is `val hash = computeHash(transactions, proofOfWork, tail.hash)`

I can give a more in depth example if you want, but don't want to take the fun out of your exercise.

Answer (score 0):

you should definitely consider Scorex, wich is written in Scala and considers a large amount of real problems with Blockchain

https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2017/12/14/scorex.html